# Capybara select option, from: dropdown

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, poltergeist

I have been trying to create a capybara test case against a simple page that includes a select box populated by the country_select gem.  In my test case I have a scenario where i try to select a country and month of birthday from the select boxes like so:

```
feature "registering for a new account" do

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

  scenario "a new user registers with a complete profile", :js => true do
    page.visit '/users/sign_up'
    select "United States", from: 'user[country]'
    select 'January', from: 'birthMonth'

    click 'sign up'

    expect(response.code).to eq '200'
  end

end
```

Capybara or Poltergeist can not see any options other than what i selected by default.  At one point I used an assert to see what options i could find

```
assert_selector(:css, 'option', minimum: 20) # countries + months should be way more than 20
```

and I got the following response:

```
Failure/Error: assert_selector(:css, 'option', minimum: 20)
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find css "option" at least 20 times, found 2 matches: "country", "month"
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
find(:xpath, '//option[contains(text(), "United States")]').select_option
find(:xpath, '//option[contains(text(), "January")]').select_option
```

This should work, given there are no ambiguous dropdown values.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not Capybara, RSpec, or Poltergeist fault.  In the controller class, I dynamically load the months of the year from a database.  This table was seeded with the months in my development DB, but not my test DB......sorry